# Allocated 4GB RAM to VM but Linux shows only about 3GB total memory

Tags: centos, virtualization

I have allocated 4GB of RAM to a VM running 32bit Linux Centos 5.5.

For unknown reason, total memory is only about 3GB.

Mem:   3107536k total,   366308k used,  2741228k free,    54900k buffers

Where has the missing 1GB gone?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default a 32bit kernel will only address the first 3G or so. You need to get a kernel with PAE support. `yum install kernel-PAE` and a reboot of the VM should let you see all 4G.

Comment: Thanks Niall, but it seems that you are missing one step which is to modify grub.conf if the boot sequence is incorrect.

Comment: Strange, didn't have to touch grub on two RHEL5 boxes I added the PAE kernel to recently!

Answer (score 9):

The 32-bit Linux kernel splits the 4 GB virtual address space of a process in two parts: 3 GB and 1 GB. The lower 3 GB of the process virtual address space is accessible as the user-space virtual addresses and the upper 1 GB space is reserved for the kernel virtual addresses. This is true for all processes.

http://www.spack.org/wiki/LinuxRamLimits